# passing variable in python array instead of string

Tags: python

I'm not sure if the title matches what I'm trying to do in Python.

I'm trying to call this function with parameters but not sure how to do it in python..

```
def PlaceOrder():
    order_data = {
    'type': 'market',
    'side': 'sell',
    'product_id': 'BTC-USD',
    'size': '0.01'
}
```

I'd like to make something like

```
def PlaceOrder(product_id,price,quantity,type):
    order_data = {
    'type': type,
    'side': quantity,
    'product_id': product_id,
    'size': price
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That code appears to be valid. Have you tried running it? You need to `return` the dictionary, but it otherwise seems fine.

Comment: Do you just need to add a return at the end to get the dictionary you made?  `return order_data`

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to pass the entire dict instead key at a time?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do because the question isn't very specific. However, my hunch is that one of these is what you're trying to do:

```
order_data={}
def PlaceOrder(product_id,price,quantity,type):
    order_data = {
    'type': type,
    'side': quantity,
    'product_id': product_id,
    'size': price
    }
```

or maybe you want:

```
def PlaceOrder(product_id,price,quantity,type):
    order_data = {
    'type': type,
    'side': quantity,
    'product_id': product_id,
    'size': price
    }
    return order_data
```

or maybe even:

```
def PlaceOrder(product_id,price,quantity,type):
    global order_data
    order_data = {
    'type': type,
    'side': quantity,
    'product_id': product_id,
    'size': price
    }
```

or are you looking for something like:

```
def PlaceOrder(product_id,price,quantity,type):
    order_data = {
    'type': type,
    'side': quantity,
    'product_id': product_id,
    'size': price
    }
    return order_data
print(PlaceOrder("BTC-USD","0.01","sell","market"))
```